# Can I configure terminal to show stderr output in different colour

Tags: terminal, color

Is it possible to configure the terminal in OS X to show `stderr` output automatically in a different colour than `stdout` output from a process?

Or is this only possible if the process is outputting coloured output?

Comment: Sadly, as of **2019** the correct answer is this is **no longer possible**. Both `hilite` and `stderred` are unmaintained and broken and I am still looking for a workaround.

Comment: @sorin I just installed `hilite` via Homebrew, it still works as expected (would be surprised if not actually, it uses very basic functionality to accomplish its task).

Comment: @sorin `stderred` may not work any longer as it seems to change the location dynamic libraries are loaded from, which may be prevented by SIP nowaydays

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no straightforward solution, but there are at least a few workarounds available to do this.

- You can install [hilite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hilite/) by building the single C file (`hilite.c` in this case) or by using `brew install hilite` (with [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed on the system). Use it as `hilite <command>`.
- You can use the command from [this answer on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/59279) (substitute `command` with the name of your script/command) to make stderr appear in red (for other colors, refer the [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php) list and change the *31m* in the below command accordingly):

  ```
    command 2> >(while IFS= read -r line; do echo -e "\e[01;31m$line\e[0m" >&2; done)
  ```
- You can use [stderred](https://github.com/sickill/stderred) to color stderr in red.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at [stderred](https://github.com/sickill/stderred) which allows to output Stderr in red.

It's OSX compatible and there is a manual to install it on OSX.